# Difference between "I'm sorry (that) S+V" and "I'm sad (that) S+V"

Tags: word-usage, difference

I don"t know the difference between "I'm **sorry** (that) S+V" and "I'm **sad** (that) S+V".

### For example,

- I'm **sorry** I went.
- I'm **sad** I went.
- I'm **sorry** you're not going to come.
- I'm **sad** you're not going to come.

Would you explain the difference to me?

Comment: Hello, have you checked the two in a dictionary? What's the difference between being sad and sorry?

Comment: You might want to use going to. And it's explain the difference to me, just for your information. Sad and sorry are different words and probably exist in your own language, too.

Answer (score 2):

"Sad" is an emotion while "sorry" is apologetic; however we can also say we are "sad" as a way to apologize for something.

> I'm **sorry** I forgot your birthday (I apologize that I forgot)
>
> I'm **sad** I forgot your birthday (I feel bad that I forgot your birthday, by which you should understand that I'm also *sorry*)

Or we can say we feel "sorry" to imply that some action has us feeling "sad".

> I'm **sad** to hear about the loss of your father.  He was such a nice man. (I feel bad that your father died, by which you should understand that I sympathize with you.)
>
> I'm **sorry** to hear about the loss of your father.  He was such a nice man.  (I feel bad that your father died, and I'm offering sympathy)

So much depends on the context.  However, I think almost every language uses emotions to convey messages. Nor is it limited to just sad/sorry:

> I was **happy** to hear that you graduated from college! (I'm offering congratulations)